# @font-face won't load in Firefox (5.01) on Wordpress-site

Tags: php, wordpress, firefox, font-face

I have a problem with a Wordpress site. The @font-face is working in Safari and Chrome but not in Firefox 5.01. I've used Fontsquirrel's font generator (http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) which generates ttf, woff, eot and svg fonts.

The problem seem to be related to the Wordpress site. I've tested a plain html site with the same font and then Firefox *is* loading and displaying the font.

I've read that the problem can be related to CMD. I've also heard that Firefox, for security reasons only load fonts if you hard code the exact URL (http://www.koodoz.com.au/klog/font-face-woe-with-wordpress-firefox/) and not the php link in Wordpress.

The php wordpress site, notworking: link.
The html site, working: link

The font won't load in Firefox. Any idea?

Comment: Just to double check, the .ttf file is linked correctly? Also, are you doing something different with your .htaccess to get your url to include the "." in "/index_wp.php/"? I'm not sure, but my gut feeling says this could be causing problems when it tries to get the .ttf file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Firefox error console:

```
Warning: @font-face rule not allowed within @media or @-moz-document rule.
Source File: http://ellenz.se/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/style.css?1312303802
Line: 18
```

And indeed, the CSS grammar does not allow nesting @-rules, though there has been talk of possibly relaxing that restriction.  WebKit is just violating the spec here.

Answer (score 1):

FF's [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) dom inspector shows that your "notworking" page's `body` style is being overridden by line 26 of your reset.css. It would appear FF is treating the `@import url` as applying AFTER the rest of your `style.css` file.

Comment: In FF, it's displaying Verdana to me, which is the fallback for the "CenturyGothicRegular", so it's not being overridden.

Comment: On FF5.0, it's displaying in "GillsSans", coming out of the reset.css. I do have a "Gills Sans" (note the space) that came from Office 2010 (I think). Since it's mispelled in the .css, I also see the fallback Verdana.

Comment: I don't know what you're seeing, but GillSans is being overriden by `font: 12px/1.2 "CenturyGothicRegular", verdana, sans-Serif;` in mine. Even if I edit the reset.css declaration using Firebug to a font that I have, Verdana is still being shown.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have a look at the [Google's font API](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/getting_started.html#Quick_Start). It's pretty easy to use and even works with IE6.

Just choose a font from the [Google Font Directory](http://code.google.com/webfonts), and then you only need to import it in your HTML-head-section (before the css):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      type="text/css" 
      href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Font+Name">
```

After that, you can use it in your css as a ragular font:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Font Name', serif;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I need to use this font (Century Gothic) and Google does not have it.